# Add classification head to segmentation-models-pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-segmentation-models

I create one of  a pytorch-segmementation-model according to [documentation](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch#start):

```
  model = smp.MAnet(
      encoder_name="efficientnet-b0",        
      encoder_weights="imagenet",    
      in_channels=3,                 
      classes=1,
```

How to add custom classifier output to encoder?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is pretty easy. SMP models has additional parameter `aux_params` as described in [docs](https://smp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/insights.html#aux-classification-output). The classification head parameters can be passed through it.

```
aux_params=dict(
    pooling='avg',             # one of 'avg', 'max'
    activation='sigmoid',      # activation function, default is None
    classes=1,                 # define number of output labels
  )

 model = smp.MAnet(
     encoder_name="efficientnet-b0", 
     encoder_weights="imagenet",    
     in_channels=3,                 
     classes=1,                    
     aux_params = aux_params
 )
```

After this setup, model will return a tuple with outputs for classification and segmentation.